# Install Ubuntu server using alternate iso from offline Linux system

Tags: 11.10, installation, server, alternate

I want to install Ubuntu server from my downloader alternate iso file for the Ubuntu server, without rebooting my machine. In other word, I want to install it while I am still on a Linux/Ubuntu system.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to install it from an offline Ubuntu system? meaning install from a installed system without restarting?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/linux-upgrade.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the procedure described in [Ubuntu installation guide here,](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/linux-upgrade.html) until the step before *Configure Apt*. In this step you have to add the ISO as the repository source. To do this, follow the following steps:

1. First mount the iso file in `/media/apt` directory. If that is not already exists, create that directory with `sudo mkdir /media/apt` command.

   ```
   sudo mount /path-to-iso-file /media/apt
   ```
2. Then add this as repository source

   ```
   sudo apt-cdrom add
   ```
3. Then do `sudo apt-get update`, most probably it is not required.

Then follow the steps in the main documentation, until *Install the Ubuntu Desktop* step. In that step, the last command should be

```
    $ sudo tasksel install ubuntu-server
```

instead of `sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop`

Hope this will answer your question.